# How can I confirm the Apple Pay payment with Stripe API

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments, applepay, passkit

So after a couple of days, I was finally able to get the token created as well the payment method, and a payment intent setup this morning. Now I'm confused on how to actually confirm the payment with Apple Pay, in the non-Apple Pay checkout flow, I had this function:

```
func paymentContext(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext, didCreatePaymentResult paymentResult: STPPaymentResult, completion: @escaping STPPaymentStatusBlock) {
        guard let paymentIntentClientSecret = paymentIntentClientSecret else {
            return;
        }
        // Collect card details
        
        
        let paymentIntentParams = STPPaymentIntentParams(clientSecret: paymentIntentClientSecret)
        paymentIntentParams.configure(with: paymentResult)
        
        
        // Submit the payment
        let paymentHandler = STPPaymentHandler.shared()
        paymentHandler.confirmPayment(paymentIntentParams, with: self) { (status, paymentIntent, error) in
            switch (status) {
            case .failed:
                self.displayFailureAlert(title: "Payment Failed", message: "There was an error trying to complete the payment, please try again later.")
                self.paymentInProgress = false
                break
            case .canceled:
                self.displayCancelledAlert(title: "Payment Canceled", message: "The payment has been cancelled.")
                self.paymentInProgress = false
                break
            case .succeeded:
                self.displaySuccessAlert(title: "Payment Succeeded", message: "The payment was successful!")
                self.paymentInProgress = false
                break
            @unknown default:
                fatalError()
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

This works great. The parameters in the `STPApplePayContext` are a bit different from the `STPPaymentContext` and I can't use the exact same functionality for it. This is the function I have for the apple Pay checkout:

```
func applePayContext(_ context: STPApplePayContext, didCreatePaymentMethod paymentMethod: STPPaymentMethod, paymentInformation: PKPayment, completion: @escaping STPIntentClientSecretCompletionBlock) {
    guard let paymentIntentClientSecret = paymentIntentClientSecret else {
        return;
    }

    let paymentIntentParams = STPPaymentIntentParams(clientSecret: paymentIntentClientSecret)
    
    
    let error = NSError()
    completion(paymentIntentClientSecret, error)
    
}
```

This is all I have so far, I tried doing `STPAPIClient.shared.confirmPaymentIntent(with:)` but nothing changed, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You will get the payment response with `retrievePaymentIntent` in the success handler and you will get all payment-related information after calling this function, Also you can fetch the data with transaction id, using [Strip API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/issuing/transactions/object).

```
func applePayContext(_ context: STPApplePayContext, didCompleteWith status: STPPaymentStatus, error: Error?) {
        switch status {
        case .success:
            // Payment succeeded, show a receipt view
            context.apiClient.retrievePaymentIntent(withClientSecret: clientSecret) { (paymentIntent, error) in
                
                print(paymentIntent?.allResponseFields ?? "")
            }
            break
        case .error:
            // Payment failed, show the error
            break
        case .userCancellation:
            // User cancelled the payment
            break
        @unknown default:
            fatalError()
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you getting the client secret here?  I followed the stripe API instructions, but there is now way to retrieve the client secret from the success handler?  I assume put it into UserDefaults or a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to follow [the instructions starting at step 7 of Stripe's documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay#handle-payment).

Specifically you need to create a Payment Intent on your server, pass its client secret to your app, then implement the delegate methods as follows:

```swift
extension CheckoutViewController {
    func applePayContext(_ context: STPApplePayContext, didCreatePaymentMethod paymentMethod: STPPaymentMethod, paymentInformation: PKPayment, completion: @escaping STPIntentClientSecretCompletionBlock) {
        let clientSecret = ... // Retrieve the PaymentIntent client secret from your backend (see Server-side step above)
        // Call the completion block with the client secret or an error
        completion(clientSecret, error);
    }

    func applePayContext(_ context: STPApplePayContext, didCompleteWith status: STPPaymentStatus, error: Error?) {
          switch status {
        case .success:
            // Payment succeeded, show a receipt view
            break
        case .error:
            // Payment failed, show the error
            break
        case .userCancellation:
            // User cancelled the payment
            break
        @unknown default:
            fatalError()
        }
    }
}
```

See also [the documentation for STPApplePayContext](https://stripe.dev/stripe-ios/docs/Classes/STPApplePayContext.html), which gives simplified high-level instructions:

> 1. Initialize this class with a PKPaymentRequest describing the payment request (amount, line items, required shipping info, etc)
> 2. Call presentApplePayOnViewController:completion: to present the Apple Pay sheet and begin the payment process 3 (optional): If you need to respond to the user changing their shipping information/shipping method, implement the optional delegate methods
> 3. When the user taps ‘Buy’, this class uses the PaymentIntent that you supply in the applePayContext:didCreatePaymentMethod:completion: delegate method to complete the payment
> 4. After payment completes/errors and the sheet is dismissed, this class informs you in the applePayContext:didCompleteWithStatus: delegate method

Comment: oh wow so literally all you need is those two lines within the `didCreatePaymentMethod` function. Just get the `clientSecret` and put it in the completion block? @Justin Michael

Comment: Yeah, that's all you need to complete the payment.  The other delegate method is required to find out what happened though!

Comment: Oh okay, so I'm doing it right, it's just my endpoint isn't sending back the clientSecret for some odd reason. Thanks for enlightening me, I genuinely thought there was something else I had to do after that step and was so frustrated. Take care. @Justin Michael